# buttonWithType' is unavailable: use object construction 'UIButton(type:)

Tags: ios, swift

In the following code, we get the error "buttonWithType' is unavailable: use object construction 'UIButton(type:)" in the following line of code below "help button" `self.hintButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.custom)`. Any suggestions. Thanks.

```
    class HUDView: UIView {

      var stopwatch: StopwatchView
      var gamePoints: CounterLabelView


    var hintButton: UIButton!

      //this should never be called
      required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
        fatalError("use init(frame:")
      }


    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        self.stopwatch = StopwatchView(frame:CGRect(x: ScreenWidth/2-150, y: 0, width: 300, height: 100))
        self.stopwatch.setSeconds(0)

    //the dynamic points label
    self.gamePoints = CounterLabelView(font: FontHUD, frame: CGRect(x: ScreenWidth-200, y: 30, width: 200, height: 70))
    gamePoints.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.38, green: 0.098, blue: 0.035, alpha: 1)
    gamePoints.value = 0

    super.init(frame:frame)

    self.addSubview(gamePoints)

    //"points" label
    let pointsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: ScreenWidth-340, y: 30, width: 140, height: 70))
    pointsLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    pointsLabel.font = FontHUD
    pointsLabel.text = " Points:"
    self.addSubview(pointsLabel)

    self.addSubview(self.stopwatch)

    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    //load the button image
    let hintButtonImage = UIImage(named: "btn")!

    //the help button
    self.hintButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.custom)
    hintButton.setTitle("Hint!", for:UIControlState())
    hintButton.titleLabel?.font = FontHUD
    hintButton.setBackgroundImage(hintButtonImage, for: UIControlState())
    hintButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 30, width: hintButtonImage.size.width, height: hintButtonImage.size.height)
    hintButton.alpha = 0.8
    self.addSubview(hintButton)
  }

  override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    //1 let touches through and only catch the ones on buttons
    let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)

    //2
    if hitView is UIButton {
      return hitView
    }

    //3
    return nil
  }

}
```

Comment: The compiler gives you a suggestion. Did you try it?

Comment: I tried, but getting "buttonWithType has been explicitly marked unavailable here". Not sure what to do.

Comment: Please read the entire error message **`use object construction 'UIButton(type:)`**

Comment: Do not ruin the question by editing and asking something completely different. Ask a new question. And yes, your original question **was** an exact duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert this

```
self.hintButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.custom)
```

to this

```
self.hintButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
```

Comment: Excellent. Works like a charm. Yes, using Swift 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write your button initialization as a compiler suggest

> use object construction 'UIButton(type:)

```
self.hintButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
```